# How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, module, auto-py-to-exe

I have this script that I originally created in Jupyter Notebooks and I saved it later on as a `.py` file, then I used `auto-py-to-exe` to convert it to an exe file. When it runs it gives me this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' [23712] Failed to execute script due to unhandled exception!`

It's importing pandas in at the top of the script, and I had used pip install to install pandas, and I thought I had all of my python `--path` variables set correctly, but clearly something still isn't set right. Is this an issue of looking at the wrong directory?

Comment: Hey new guy, so why dont you show us your import line, maybe you are writing import pandas as pd, which causes therror or maybe you just didnt install it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a somewhat common issue with `auto-py-to-exe`. I'd suggest reading through [this blog post](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe) by the author for solutions to this and many other issues. If you skip to [here](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/?utm_source=auto_py_to_exe#how-to-fix-specific-issues), the suggested solution is as follows:

> ### ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x / ImportError: No module named x
>
> This means a particular module ('x' in this case) was not added to the package. I have seen this occur with packages in the pandas library and win32api; as long as you can identify the package (e.g. 'x'), then it is very easy to fix.
>
> To fix this in the UI, open the advanced tab and find the `--hidden-import` input. Simply paste the module name into this input and then repackage. If the original error is still appearing, you have done this incorrectly.

Comment: Hugs and kisses to you good sir! That worked perfectly. Thanks